# Standard way to pull filenames from headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, cross-browser

Specifically, the way I'm currently doing it is leaving quotes on the filename, which results in the file being named wrong.

Sample code:

```
$http.post("/Controller/Method", jsonObject).then(function (response) {
    var header = response.headers('Content-Disposition');
    var filename = header.split("filename=");
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href", dataStr);
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", filename[1]);
    dlAnchorElem.click();
});
```

When I breakpoint and check filename[1], it has ""filename.ext"", instead of "filename.ext" like I'm expecting.  The resulting file's name is:

-filename.ext-

If it matters, I control the C# ASP.NET Controller that's handling the server-side code, which is doing this:

```
ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition { FileName = fileName, Inline = true, };
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
string fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath)
```